# ASP.NET MVC2 - passing a parameter to a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

This is for a project I'm doing in the university. We're using ASP.NET MVC2 to build a mini-prototype of a website just to show what we can do.

Now, I have a controller called `ItemController.cs`, a view `Item/Index.aspx`, a model `Item.cs` and a ViewModel `ViewItems.cs`. I use the ViewModel to pass information to the view from the controller. My question is - how do I call a controller method with parameters? Currently, I use

```
Html.ActionLink("View Event Items", "Index", "Item")
```

which points to `ItemController`'s `Index()` method. Say I want it to take an `int` parameter (`Index(int eventId)`) How would I write the ActionLink to pass the parameter to it?

Also, if I have any errors in how I think this stuff works, please feel free to point them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the routevalues object (or RouteValuesDictionary) to pass values to your action.
In your example it would look like this:

```
Html.ActionLink("View Event Items", "Index", "Item", new { eventId = 1}, new {})
```

...where 2 is your event id. The second empty object (new {}) is for html attributes. Nate's answer is close, but I don't think there is an overload that takes a routevalues object as the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
Html.ActionLink("View Event Items", new { controller = "Item", action = "Index", id = 5 })
```

should get you in the vicinity of where you're looking to go.